# Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Tags: android

I am trying to do a program using android studio and this program 
is for the last year in the university so I needed to use 
navigation drawer in my project but when I used it appeared to me 
this problem

```
Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem I will 
appreciate this thing

this my code for the home page

```
    package com.example.healthcaresystem;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

    import android.view.View;

    import androidx.navigation.NavController;
    import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
    import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
    import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

    import android.view.Menu;

    public class HomeUserOnlineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_user_online);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
            DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
            // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
            mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                    R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                    R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                    .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                    .build();
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_user_online, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                    || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
        }
    }
```

this is my XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_home_user_online"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_user_online"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_home_user_online_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and these are my dependencies

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.healthcaresystem"
            minSdkVersion 26
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'


        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.1.0'


        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'


        implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.5'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'


        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
        implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
        implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml needs to make use of

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
....
....
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

instead of the deprecated `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` you currently have. Your java class is importing the relevant package using `import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;`

Answer (score 0):

Please import valid class for your drawer layout in java file

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Do not import androidx drawer layout.